# How to programmatically register a service in the SCR using OSGi standard features?

Tags: java, osgi

I've spent some time experimenting with and studying the OSGi enRoute site. The [Quick Start](http://enroute.osgi.org/qs/050-start.html), and [Base](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_base/050-start.html) tutorials were really good. Now as a learning exercise, I'm creating my own example following the principles in those tutorials.

I've decided to reproduce the `StageService` from the blog post "[Making JavaFX better with OSGi](http://paulonjava.blogspot.com/2014/11/making-javafx-better-with-osgi.html)". Rather than using the `org.apache.felix.dm` and `org.apache.felix.dm.annotation.api` packages I want to use the OSGi standard SCR packages (`org.osgi.service.component.*`) along with the enRoute provider template.

So far everything has worked out nicely. But I'm stuck on one point. In the "Making JavaFX better with OSGi" tutorial the service is programmatically registered into the service registry using the `org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager` like this:

```
 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

  BundleContext bc = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
  DependencyManager dm = new DependencyManager(bc);

  dm.add(dm.createComponent()
    .setInterface(StageService.class.getName(), null)
    .setImplementation(new StageServiceImpl(primaryStage)));
 }
```

My assumption is that in this example the `DependencyManager` is an Apache Felix specific feature rather than an OSGi standard. I would like to have my enRoute provider depend only on OSGi standard features.

So my question is simply:

1. How would one register a service in the service registry programmatically using only OSGi standard features? (*I know from following the enRoute tutorials that if my component implements the exported service that SCR will automatically register my component in the service registry when my component is activated. The problem with this solution though is that when my component is activated it has to launch the JavaFX application in a different thread so as to not block the thread in use by the SCR until the JavaFX application terminates. Because of this, my component must programmatically register the service in the service registry. Otherwise it won't be guaranteed to be available upon registration.*)

For reference, here is what I currently have:

```
private void registerService(Stage stage) {
    DependencyManager dm = new DependencyManager(bundle().getBundleContext());
    dm.add(
        dm.createComponent()
          .setInterface(StageService.class.getName(), null)
          .setImplementation(new StageServiceImpl(primaryStage))
    );
}
```

But instead I want to replace it with this:

```
private void registerService(Stage stage) {
    // How to register service in service registry using only OSGi standard features? (not the apache felix dependency manager)
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Following BJ Hargrave's recommendation I tried to register the service directly from the bundle context as follows:

```
FrameworkUtil
  .getBundle(getClass())
  .getBundleContext()
  .registerService(StageService.class, new StageServiceImpl(primaryStage), null);
```

After doing this and trying to resolve the enRoute application project the following error occurs:

> org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve
>   <> version=null: missing requirement
>   com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.application 
>   ->  Unable to resolve com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.application
>   version=1.0.0.201608172037: missing requirement
>   objectClass=com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.api.StageService]

I have uploaded the project to [github](https://github.com/axiopisty/com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx) so you can reproduce the error.

**Update 2**

The build tab in the bnd.bnd file in the provider module shows the following warning:

```
The servicefactory:=true directive is set but no service is provided, ignoring it
```

Might this have something to do with the application module not being able to be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the OSGi spec would help you understand the service API.

But this should do it:

`ServiceRegistration<StageService> reg = bc.registerService(StageService.class, new StageServiceImpl(primaryStage), null);`

Comment: I actually tried that, but the build tab in the provider module bnd.bnd file states: "The servicefactory:=true directive is set but no serive is provided, ignoring it. The run tab does resolve fine. But when I try to resolve the application module I get: ...ResolutionException: Unable to resolve <<INITIAL>> version=null: missing requirement com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.application 
->  Unable to resolve com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.application version=1.0.0.201608172025: missing requirement objectClass=com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.api.StageService]

Comment: You asked how to register a service with the OSGi api. Which I then showed. Now you are asking another question which I am not sure I understand. I don't know the details of the example you are working with so I cannot really help.

Comment: Your application references a StageService: https://github.com/axiopisty/com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx/blob/master/com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.application/src/com/github/axiopisty/osgi/javafx/launcher/application/LauncherApplication.java#L25-L26. This will cause the resulting bundle to declare that osgi.service requirement in its manifest. Since the provider does not use DS to provide the service (you are using the OSGi to register it), the resolver cannot find anyone to provide the service. You can added a Provide-Capability for the service to the provider's manifest.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it does answer the question in my original post. Thank you. I am still having problems getting this example to run though. Would you mind submitting a PR on that github repository which would show me how to get the application to run with the Provide-Capability and Require-Capability headers?

Comment: I noticed that the http://enroute.osgi.org/services/osgi.enroute.capabilities.html is blank. Maybe this would be a good example application for providing and requiring capabilities? I'd be happy to contribute it to the enroute project if only I could get this example to work.

Comment: Hey! I got it. Thank you so much. It required the following to be added to the provider module bnd.bnd file: Provide-Capability: osgi.service;objectClass="com.github.axiopisty.osgi.javafx.launcher.api.StageService"

Answer (score 4):

In rare cases it is necessary to register a 'service by hand' using the standard OSGi API. Try very hard to avoid this case because if you start to register (and maybe depend) on services that you manually register you get a lot of responsibility that is normally hidden from view. For example, you have to ensure that the services you register are also unregistered.

One of the rare cases where this is necessary is when you have to wait for a condition before you can register your service. For example, you need to poll a piece of hardware before you register a service for the device. You will need to control the CPU but at that moment you cannot yet register a service. In that case you create an `immediate` component and register the service manually.

To register a service manually you require a `BundleContext` object. You can get that objectvia the activate method, just declare a Bundle Context in its arguments and it is automatically injected:

```
@Activate
void activate( BundleContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

You can now register a service with the bundle context:

```
void register(MyService service) {
    Hashtable<String,Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
    properties.put("foo", "bar");
    this.registration = context.registerService( MyService.class, service, properties );
}
```

However, you now have the responsibility to unregister this service in your deactivate. If you do not clean up this service then your *component* might be deactivated while your service still floats around. Your service is *unmanaged*. (Although when the *bundle* is stopped it will be cleaned up.)

```
@Deactivate
void deactivate() {
   if ( this.registration != null)
     this.registration.unregister();
}
```

If you create the service is a call back or background thread then you obviously have to handle the concurrency issues. You must ensure that there is no race condition that you register a service while the deactivate method has finished.

This text has also been added to the [DS Page](http://enroute.osgi.org/doc/217-ds.html) of OSGi enRoute

Comment: what if you must instantiate the `MyService` object by hand as well?  Would we then be responsible for invoking `myService.activate(context)`?  My experimentation says yes, but it seems like register should do that for us

Comment: The example assumes you've instantiated MyService. If you want, you can give it the context in the constructor. So not sure what you ask?